# Receiving an empty [] json in nodejs and mongo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

First of all, I'm sorry for my English.

I have a problem in nodejs and mongo, I've created a schema with this code:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var forumSchema = new Schema({
        foro:[{
                universidad:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "College"},
                topics:[{
                        usercreator:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"User"},
                        titulo:{ type: String },
                        posts:[{
                                mensaje:{ type: String },
                                username:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User"}
                            }]
                }]
        }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Forum', forumSchema);
```

and I've created a Json and I've imported it to mongo:

```js
{
  "_id": {"$oid":"567895dd239410651a8e4df8"},
  "foro":[
    {
      "universidad":"566b279b747cfb38bc2830df",
      "topics":[
        {
          "usercreator": "566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e7",
          "titulo": "parking cercano",
          "posts": [
            {
              "mensaje": "hay parking cerca de la uni?",
              "username": "566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e7"
            },
            {
              "mensaje": "si, tiene uno grande justo al lado",
              "username": "566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e5"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "usercreator":"566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e5",
          "titulo":"horario",
          "posts":[
            {
              "mensaje":"solo hay horario de mañana?",
              "username":"566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e5"
            },
            {
              "mensaje":"no, también de tardes",
              "username":"566df8c2c7d87f1a47fda4e7"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the problem is that when I'm trying to GET it in POSTMAN I'm receiving an empty json like: [].

The code of the controller is:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Forum  = mongoose.model('Forum');
var College = mongoose.model('College');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

//GET - Return all forum
exports.AllForum = function(req, res) {
    console.log('all forum');
    Forum.find(function(err, forum) {
        User.populate(forum, {path:"User", select:"username"},function(err, forum){});
        College.populate(forum, {path:"College", select:"college"},function(err, forum) {});
        if (err) res.send(500, err.message);
        console.log('GET /forum' + JSON.stringify(forum));
        res.status(200).jsonp(forum);
    });
};
```

Console returns the Log "all forum" so the code is being executed, but I don't know why doesn't work.

Does anyone know? Thanks!!

PD: I can see the full json with the command line in mongo.

Comment: What does this line prints console.log('GET /forum' + JSON.stringify(forum)); ?

Comment: To see in console what json contains. It shows the same that postman.

Answer (score 0):

jsonp this one expect a callback when you request it from postman.

replace it with `res.status(200).json(forum);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It doesn't work, I also tried with .send(forum) but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty query object to your *Forum.find* operation. And it looks like your trying to populate some fields within each returned forum document, so try chaining *.populate* like this.

```
exports.AllForum = function(req, res) {
    console.log('all forum');
    Forum.find({})
        .populate('foro.universidad', 'field1 field2')
        .populate('foro.topics.usercreator', 'field1 field2')
        .populate(...)
        .exec(function(err, forum) {
            if (err) {return res.status(500).send(err.message);}
            console.log('GET /forum' + JSON.stringify(forum));
            res.status(200).jsonp(forum);
        });
};
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I've tried this but doesn't work. In fact, if I don't use the populate, Postman also shows me an empty json.